# Raspberry pi 4B 8 GB: Slow network performance with shared samba directory

Tags: networking, samba

I've set up an Raspberry pi in a network with Gigabit NICs.
On an SSD I have set up an shared SMB directory. The SSD itself writes with more than 400 Mbyte/s. Due to an encryption this drops to 160-200 Mbytes/s. Still, when I do an upload, it maxes out at 30 Mbyte/s. I would expect 100-110 Mbyte/s in this particular network setting. What can I do to increase performance?

EDIT: I checked which speed I get via a wired connection to the network switch. Here I receive 65 Mbyte/s in reading and 50 Mbyte/s in writing. Is this bottleneck caused by the CPU of the rasberry? As mentioned earlier: The SSD as well as the network should support full Gbit speed... What is your bandwhich?

Answer (score 0):

I have an RPi4 NAS with two HDDs myself and get gigabit speeds. But of course only when the HDDs are connected to the USB 3.0 ports. USB 2 is about 30MB/s. So you probably have the hard drives on the USB 2 ports.

Comment: No of course not. As I wrote, I get up to 200 Mbytes write speed with ```dd``` if I write direct to the partition of the drive. It is only with smb, the bandwhich drops. CPU is also not maxed out.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the speeds were from another PC. Maybe this link will help you. https://superuser.com/questions/713248/home-file-server-using-samba-has-slow-read-and-write-speed.

Comment: OK, I tested the network and with iperf I get about 960 Mbit over the network swith.
Therefore the ethernet is not thr problem here. I am wondering: What speed do you get out of the box with smb and the raspberry pi4? My version is the 8 GB.

Comment: Sorry for the late response! Depending on the type of file I'm copying, I can get up to 120 MB/s (960 Mbit/s) with, for exaple, large video- or .iso-files. On the other hand, if I copy a folder with many small text files (e.g. code, etc.), the speed drops down to a few MB/s, because the creation of new documents takes time.
So it is "faster" to copy one big file instead of many small ones.